# znapzend DST file system

Tags: znapzend

I'm working with a new znapzend environment. The snapshots are happening, and I have just one destination, a remote server set up just to store the archived data. It appears the data stored on the DST is only one revision of the data, and I'm assuming that is the latest. In other words, with each new snapshot, is the currently archived data on the remote server just being overwritten? If so, how do I get a history, for example the version of a particular file from a month ago as opposed to an hour ago? It may be I'm just not understanding how it works yet. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

ZnapZend works by running `zfs snapshot` in regular intervals on your SRC file-set. It then uses `zfs send/receive` to transfer these snapshots to the DST fileset. If you run `zfs list SRC/DST` you will not see anything of the snapshots.

Run `zfs list -r -t snapshot DST` to see the snapshots on the destination fileset.

You need to specify sensible plans for both source and destination filesets. Eg `1week=>1day,1month=>1week,1year=>1month` for source and `4week=>1day,3month=>1week,3year=>1month` for destination